# Upgrade a ReplaceXlipse Eclipse-Plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Can anyone upgrade (or fork) this plugin :
https://github.com/hawkxu/ReplaceXlipse

it seems to be out of date.

I have attempted to update locally the plugin, in STS 4.12 adding folder /lib with jaxb depenency:

```
codemodel.jar
dtd-parser.jar
FastInfoset.jar
istack-commons-runtime.jar
istack-commons-tools.jar
javax.activation-api.jar
javax.xml.stream-3.0.1.jar
jaxb-api.jar
jaxb-jxc.jar
jaxb-runtime.jar
jaxb-xjc.jar
relaxng-datatype.jar
rngom.jar
stax-ex.jar
txw2.jar
w3c-dom.jar
xsom.jar
```

If I start it from PDT as 'Run As -> Eclipse Application' it seems work; but after coping jar in plugin folder and restart STS it not work :
'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext'.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: The package `java.xml.bind` has been removed from the system library in Java 11. You have to provide it via a plugin/bundle (recommended) or use Java 10 or lower to run it (not recommended).

Comment: STS use org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.2.v20210201-0955/jre/bin 
i have configured  plugin.xml adding jaxb libraries and its dependency in tab runtime-> classpath and i put in 'Exported Package' this:
com.sun.istack,
 com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.relaxng,
 com.sun.xml.txw2,
 com.sun.xml.xsom,
 javax.activation,
 javax.xml.bind,
 javax.xml.stream,
 org.jvnet.staxex

It seems work when i start the plugin directly from STS; but if i install it in STS (copy jar in plugins folder) it raise the exception.

Comment: You also need `Import-Package: java.xml.bind` in the plugin/bundle where it is used (to get the plugin/bundle started that provides `java.xml.bind`). By the way, as far as I know Eclipse Orbit provides a plugin/bundle containing `java.xml.bind` so you do not have to build it yourself.

Comment: Hi howlger,
i apreciate your help, however after many attempts, configure dependency of plugin seems impossible for me...
i have forked it :https://github.com/Savers80/ReplaceXlipse.git

When sts seems compile correctly, when i export the plugin (generate errors like 'cannot be resolved to a type'  or 'accessible from More than one module matches' ).
I have read similar posts (where u have answered too)  Is clear  causes of errors, but  not the solution...
Best regards